# Unable to cycle through image gallery with jquery selection

Tags: jquery

Noob in jQuery.

I'm trying to cycle through an image gallery with the goal of having the images fade in and fade out.

Here is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78Fky/)
By clicking on `#gallery` each image fadeTo(arg1) and then fadeTo(args2).
But I want them to go one by one.
Perhaps a `delay` should be added to the chain?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason you're not just using one of the bajillion preexisting jQuery image gallery plugins?

Comment: I want to learn how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery animations (as most things on javascript) are asynchronous, which means that the function calls return before the action has finished. In a sense, you can think of each iteration of your `$('img').each` loop as following:

- jQuery calls your function with `this` bound to one `img` element
- Your function calls `fade` on `$(this)`
- jQuery then asks the browser to *schedule* an animation to be run
- Your function returns

Then, *after* all your iterations have ended the browser will start to make the animations happen on the screen, all at the same time (since all of them were scheduled).

To create a sequential behavior, you can give the `fade` function a callback:

```
$('#gallery').click(function(evt) {
  var remainingImages = $("img").toArray();

  var processNext = function() {
    var image = remainingImages.shift();
    if(!image) return;

    // Add the next iteration as a callback to the animation
    $(image).fadeTo(500, .3).fadeTo(250, 1, processNext);
  };

  processNext();
});
```

Then, instead of scheduling all animations at once, what happens is something like this:

- All the current `img` elements are stored in the `remainingImages` array
- The `processNext` function is called, which removes the first image from the array
- The function calls `fade` on the `$(image)`, providing a function (that happens to be itself) that should be called *after* the animation is finished
- jQuery schedules the animation with the browser, and tells it to execute the function afterwards
- After the animation finishes, the next iteration is executed

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78Fky/2/)

Comment: This works.  I'm marking it correct but can you clarify please.  When I select `$('img')` and then do `.each(function(){...});` does this not take each `img` and cycle through them, applying whatever function?  And you're saying that because of asynchronous it fires off every single image?

Comment: @wisfool I've tried to clarify it a bit. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: yeah... makes more sense now.  When the fade finishes on the `image` the processNext is called.  Thanks for the walk through!